# WPF Styling and Templating over many buttons?

Tags: wpf, binding, styles, controltemplate, relativesource

I can't seem to get the correct combination to get the desired effect:

Current XAML:

```
<Button Content="Foo" prism:Click.Command="{Binding FooCommand}"
        Visibility="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={ncon:VisibilityBooleanConverter}}" />
<Button Content="Bar" prism:Click.Command="{Binding BarCommand}"
        Visibility="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={ncon:VisibilityBooleanConverter}}" />
```

I want to extract out the `Visibility="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={ncon:VisibilityBooleanConverter}}"` as a style to apply over all the Buttons (within this UserControl resources). I can't seem to get the correct combination going here to make that happen.

Basically, what it does is instead of just disabling the button based on the `ICommand.CanExecute` it takes that DependencyProperty and binds it to the Visibility of the Button using a boolean-visiblity converter so the button is not only disabled, but also collapsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Style would look like this i suppose:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Visibility"
            Value="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={ncon:VisibilityBooleanConverter}}"/>
</Style>
```

Doesn't that work?

Comment: That works... I guess I made the error that I was trying to use TemplateBinding to avoid doing RelativeSource, which didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={ncon:VisibilityBooleanConverter}}" Value="Visible">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```